# Regular expression to strip thousand separator from numeral string?

Tags: javascript, regex, language-agnostic

I have strings which contains thousand separators, however no string-to-number function wants to consume it correctly (using JavaScript). I'm thinking about "preparing" the string by stripping all thousand separators, leaving anything else untoched and letting `Number`/`parseInt`/`parseFloat` functions (I'm satisfied with their behavious otherwise) to decide the rest. But it seems what i have no idea which RegExp can do that!

Better ideas are welcome too!

---

### UPDATE:

Sorry, answers enlightened me how badly formulated question it is. What i'm triyng to achieve is: 1) to strip thousand separators only if any, but 2) to not disturb original string much so i will get NaNs in the cases of invalid numerals.

### MORE UPDATE:

JavaScript is limited to English locale for parsing, so lets assume thousand separator is ',' for simplicity (naturally, it never matches decimal separator in any locale, so changing to any other locale should not pose a problem)

Now, on parsing functions:

```
parseFloat('1023.95BARGAIN BYTES!')  // parseXXX functions just "gives up" on invalid chars and returns 1023.95
Number('1023.95BARGAIN BYTES!')      // while Number constructor behaves "strictly" and will return NaN
```

Sometimes I use rhw loose one, sometimes strict. I want to figure out the best approach for preparing string for both functions.

On validity of numerals:

`'1,023.99'` is perfectly well-formed English number, and stripping all commas will lead to correct result.
`'1,0,2,3.99'` is broken, however generic comma stripping will give `'1023.99'` which is unlikely to be a correct result.

Comment: Is your separator a comma, or a dot? That is, is twelve thousand represented as '12,000', or as '12.000'? (Or something else?)

Comment: @ruakh, actually a space, but it is not relevant, because JavaScript is not locale-capable at all.

Comment: It is relevant, because your regex will have to know which separator to remove!

Comment: please give an example of the string before and after, for instance: `12 345 678` ==> `12345678` or `he said, 'I just won $25 000 000!!!'` ==> `he said, 'I just won $25000000!!!'` or `there are 5,280 feet in a mile, right?` ==> `there are 5280 feet in a mile, right?` or whatever you can think of

Comment: @Code Jockey, i've updated the question, hope its better

Comment: I think we're still going to need more. "is unlikely to be correct" is not very clear. What should the code do? What should be the result?

Comment: @Jan Kuča, check out my last comment to your answer. Since `'1,0,2,3.99'` do not contain valid thousand separators, code should not strip them, cause `parseFloat` to "give up" and return `1` and `Number` to return `NaN`

Comment: this regular expression worked for me: ,(?=\d{3})

Answer (score 7, accepted):

welp, I'll venture to throw my suggestion into the pot:

**Note: Revised**

```
stringWithNumbers = stringwithNumbers.replace(/(\d+),(?=\d{3}(\D|$))/g, "$1");
```

should turn

```
1,234,567.12
1,023.99
1,0,2,3.99
the dang thing costs $1,205!!
95,5,0,432
12345,0000
1,2345
```

into:

```
1234567.12
1023.99
1,0,2,3.99
the dang thing costs $1205!!
95,5,0432
12345,0000
1,2345
```

I hope that's useful!

**EDIT:**

There is an additional alteration that may be necessary, but is not without side effects:

```
(\b\d{1,3}),(?=\d{3}(\D|$))
```

This changes the "one or more" quantifier (`+`) for the first set of digits into a "one to three" quantifier (`{1,3}`) and adds a "word-boundary" assertion before it. It will prevent replacements like `1234,123` ==> `1234123`. However, it will also prevent a replacement that *might* be desired (if it is preceded by a letter or underscore), such as `A123,789` or `_1,555` (which will remain unchanged).

Comment: I guess i found a bug, `'30,0300'.replace(/(\d+),(?=\d{3})/g, "$1")` still strips a comma. How can i adjust lookahead assertion to stop after exactly 3 digits?

Comment: `.replace(/(\d+),(?=\d{3})(\D|$)/g, "$1$2");`

Comment: @Jan Kuča, '1,030,000'.replace(/(\d+),(?=\d{3})(\D|$)/g, "$1$2") returns "1,030,000"

Comment: @user539484 - the solution I believe you seek has been added to my answer. It quite close to the solution Jan Kuča proposed, but includes the non-digit match INSIDE the look-ahead assertion.

Comment: @JanKuča - very close, except that the placement of the "non-digit or end assertion" match must not be part of the match, but instead part of the look-ahead assertion. When it is expressed as part of the match, it will reject any valid matches because it is attempted on the same characters as the previous look-ahead. After matching one or more numbers, it matches the comma. It then looks ahead to assert that there are three more digits. If there are three digits, then a "non-digit or end" match is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `num.replace(/,/g, '')` should be sufficient I think.

Comment: But what if input numeral is not well-formed, eg `'1,02,4'`?

Comment: Well then those are not thousand separators. If that should be interpreted as 1024, then the code to get that value is the same.

Comment: Problem is: simple approach will take those as thousand separators and i will get 1024 while correct results (for JavaScript environment) `parseInt('1,02,4') == 1`, `Number('1,02,4') == NaN`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your thousand separator is

```
myString = myString.replace(/[ ,]/g, "");
```

would remove spaces and commas.

Comment: JavaScript strings don't have a `replaceAll` method. Maybe you're thinking of Java?

Comment: @ruakh: Yeah, I had fixed it by the time your comment got through though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
var decimalCharacter = ".",
    regex = new RegExp("[\\d" + decimalCharacter + "]+", "g"),
    num = "10,0000,000,000.999";
+num.match(regex).join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

To confirm that a numeral-string is well-formed, use:

```
/^(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+)($|[^\d])/.test(numeral_string)
```

which will return `true` if the numeral-string is either (1) just a sequence of zero or more digits, or (2) a sequence of digits with a comma before each set of three digits, or (3) either of the above followed by a non-digit character and who knows what else. (Case #3 is for floats, as well as your "BARGAIN BYTES!" examples.)

Once you've confirmed that, use:

```
numeral_string.replace(/,/g, '')
```

which will return a copy of the numeral-string with all commas excised.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following in a commercial setting, and it has worked often:

`numberStr = numberStr.replace(/[. ,](\d\d\d\D|\d\d\d$)/g,'$1');`

In the above example, thousands can be marked with a decimal, a comma, or a space.

In some cases ( like a price of 1000,5 Euros) the above doesn't work. If you need something more robust, this should work 100% of the time:

```
//convert a comma or space used as the cent placeholder to a decimal
$priceStr = $priceStr.replace(/[, ](\d\d$)/,'.$1');
$priceStr = $priceStr.replace(/[, ](\d$)/,'.$1');
//capture cents
var $hasCentsRegex = /[.]\d\d?$/;
if($hasCentsRegex.test($priceStr)) {
    var $matchArray = $priceStr.match(/(.*)([.]\d\d?$)/);
    var $priceBeforeCents = $matchArray[1];
    var $cents = $matchArray[2];    
} else{
    var $priceBeforeCents = $priceStr;
    var $cents = "";
}
//remove decimals, commas and whitespace from the pre-cent portion
$priceBeforeCents = $priceBeforeCents.replace(/[.\s,]/g,'');
//re-create the price by adding back the cents
$priceStr = $priceBeforeCents + $cents;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `s.replaceAll("(\\W)(?=\\d{3})","");`

This regex gets all alpha-numeric character with 3 characters after it.

Strings like `4.444.444.444,00 €` will be `4444444444,00 €`